# Does new GCM(C2DM) permission that comes with the new Parse Android SDK disable auto update for current app users?

Tags: android, permissions, push-notification, parse-platform, android-c2dm

After updating Parse Android SDK (1.4.3) during the renewal of our project, we now have a new permission in our AndroidManifest.xml file. These new permission rows writes as follows;

`<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />`

What we're suspicious about is that these new permission might disable auto updates for our current users.

What's your opinion about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

GCM permissions are added as "receive data from internet" under "Wifi connection information" permission group. If you already have a permission within the group then auto update would not be blocked but if its the first permission within the permission group then auto update will be blocked.

You can refer : https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en